# Java how to programmatically initialize 2d object array?

Tags: java

```
Object[][] dataEntriesg = {
        {"","","","",""},
        {"","","","",""},
        {"","","","",""},
        {"","","","",""},
        {"","","","",""},
        {"","","","",""},
        {"","","","",""},
        {"","","","",""},
        {"","","","",""},
        {"","","","",""},
        {"","","","",""},
        {"","","","",""},
        {"","","","",""},
        {"","","","",""},
        {"","","","",""},
        {"","","","",""},
        {"","","","",""},
        {"","","","",""},
        {"","","","",""},
        {"","","","",""},
        {"","","","",""},
        {"","","","",""},
        {"","","","",""},
        {"","","","",""},
        {"","","","",""},
};
```

I want to initialize 2d array such as this.
the way I am doing it is so stupid.
How can I use a loop to do it?
I have tried to put it in for loop. But seems {} can be used only at declaration.

Comment: You could use a single loop, but I think you'll find a compound `for-loop` easier (two loops, one within the other...)

Comment: Btw why Object? Those are Strings...

Comment: @m0skit0 coz I need to pass in this in to a function requires object[][] type

Comment: @BufBills Then why are you creating String array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataEntriesg.length ; i++) {
    Arrays.fill(dataEntriesg [i], "");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a compound `for-loop`, something like...

```
dataEntriesg = new Object[25][5];
for (int row = 0; row < dataEntriesg.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < dataEntriesg[row].length; col++) {
        dataEntriesg[row][col] = "";
    }
}
```

...for example

Answer (score 1):

Used my sample as a **blue print**

**For example**, suppose `x = new int[3][4]`, `x[0]`, `x[1]`, and `x[2]` are one-dimensional
arrays and each contains four elements, as shown in the figure `x.length` is `3`, and
`x[0].length`, `x[1].length`, and `x[2].length` are `4`

[image]

How to traverse and intilize the 2D array you can follow following sample as your **blue print**:

[image]